# Fading in text via text button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am currently working in WordPress and I want to fade in a bit of text by clicking on another text line.
I just want purely text (For example text as a button) and have a nice fade-in effect.

I have already tried this but it does not work in wordpress.
I got this from somewhere online:

http://jsfiddle.net/zcWJ6/11/

html:

```
<span class="button">Text button</span>
<span class="fadein">You just clicked on "Text button"</span>
```

css:

```
.button { cursor: pointer; }
```

Jquery:

```
$('.fadein').hide();

$('.button').on('click', function(){
     $('.fadein').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: you need to share your markup and what you have tried

Comment: Maybe you check the docs for jquery. (https://jqueryui.com/show/)

Comment: In wordpress use `jQuery` not `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Satpal is right on this one, you need to use jQuery rather than $ when working in wordpress. The new code would look like this:

```
jQuery('.fadein').hide();

jQuery('.button').on('click', function(){
     jQuery('.fadein').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

the code above should work just fine in wordpress for what you want to do, assuming you have the jQuery library already called and you're putting the code in the right place. As @Giancarlo mentioned you should also wrap it in a document ready script, but it also needs to be in jQuery form like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.fadein').hide();

    jQuery('.button').on('click', function(){
         jQuery('.fadein').fadeIn(2000);
    });
});
```

put this code into a separate .js file and call it in your theme's functions.php file using [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your jQuery code after the jQuery JavaScript library has loaded. Additionally, wrap your jQuery code around an on document ready scope.

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready()
$(function(){
  // Your jQuery code goes here
});
```